# ORACLE SQL one to many relationship?

Tags: oracle

Let's see if I can try to explain what I'm trying to do.

I have a table where each row has a begin date (`begin_date`) and end date (`end_date`). this table has a key (`person_key`)

I have another table where that `person_key` could have multiple entries each with a `begin_date` and `end_date` and an associated value.

example:

```
Table 1
key      begin_date     end_date
123      1/1/2016       1/31/2016
123      2/1/2016       2/29/2016
123      3/1/2016       3/31/2016
```

Table 2

```
key      begin_date     end_date     value
123      1/15/2016      2/16/2016      X
123      2/17/2016      12/31/2099     Y
```

What I want to be able to do in SQL is write a query that will produce the following results:

Table 3

```
key      begin_date     end_date    value
123      1/1/2016       1/31/2016     X
123      2/1/2016       2/16/2016     X
123      2/17/2016      2/29/2016     Y
123      3/1/2016       3/31/2016     Y
```

This may be way too involved as a simple solution but just looking for some guidance!

Comment: Can you post some SQL where you have tried to get the result?  Also can you provide some clarification about the requirements?

Comment: Why would the output have a value of `x` between 1/1 and 1/14 if the value didn't exist until 1/15?

Comment: Please express your requirements as *business logic* instead of expecting us to infer them from some confusing data sets.